# Get number of children a tag has with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I a trying to count the number of children a certain div tag has.
I have gone about doing this in different ways but none have been successful.
Through expecting the elements I have found that the xpath of the element whose children I wish to count is the following one:

```
//*[@id="myShipments"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]
```

This element currently has 25 children of the following type:

```
//*[@id="myShipments"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[0]
//*[@id="myShipments"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]
//*[@id="myShipments"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]
...
```

Using the find_elements_by_xpath function I have made the following

```
numberOfChildren = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="myShipments"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]') // sets it to 1
numberOfChildren = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="myShipments"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]//*') // sets it to 541, I assume it also counts the children of the children
numberOfChildren = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="myShipments"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[0-9]') // sets it to 0, I assume the last div is incorrect
```

This is the full HMTL of the table: https://codeshare.io/5wJ0Vp

This is the simplified version:

[image: Table]

How can I count the number of the children (the shipmentsTable__tableBody--row divs) that the parent div has (the myShimpents__shipmentsTable--tableBody div)? Is it possible to use a regular expression to fetch all the divs of the last div in the xpath, and if so how?

Comment: Is there any HTML that can be share?

Comment: @frianH question edited

Comment: I can't see `//*[@id="myShipments"]` in the page. But I have answer for your state : ***How can I count the number of the children (the shipmentsTable__tableBody--row divs) that the parent div has (the myShimpents__shipmentsTable--tableBody div)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below approach.

Use **css selector**:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.myShipments__shipmentsTable--tableBody div.shipmentsTable__tableBody--row')
```

Use **xpath**:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="myShipments__shipmentsTable--tableBody"]//div[@class="shipmentsTable__tableBody--row"]')
```